# React-Native and WebPack Hello World. Web Build not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, webpack

I have cloned this github project: [github project](https://github.com/kauffecup/react-native-web-hello-world)
I've installed webpack globally. "I'm not sure if this is the issue, because I tried with a local version of webpack and it still didn't work"

I can't run the project. I am under the impression that if you download everything from a project, your `package.json`, and all `configuration` files should provide all the details for what npm needs to do to "install", and run a project. Am I missing something else?

I tried to run the project using

> npm run web-dev
>
> Here is the output npm-debug.log

```
 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'web-dev' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preweb-dev', 'web-dev', 'postweb-dev' ]
5 info lifecycle ClubApp@0.0.1~preweb-dev: ClubApp@0.0.1
6 silly lifecycle ClubApp@0.0.1~preweb-dev: no script for preweb-dev, continuing
7 info lifecycle ClubApp@0.0.1~web-dev: ClubApp@0.0.1
8 verbose lifecycle ClubApp@0.0.1~web-dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle ClubApp@0.0.1~web-dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\clark\Documents\Test\ClubApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\clark\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\clark\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
10 verbose lifecycle ClubApp@0.0.1~web-dev: CWD: C:\Users\clark\Documents\Test\ClubApp
11 silly lifecycle ClubApp@0.0.1~web-dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
11 silly lifecycle   'webpack-dev-server --content-base web/public/ --config web/webpack/web.dev.config.js --port 3001 --inline --hot --colors' ]
12 silly lifecycle ClubApp@0.0.1~web-dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle ClubApp@0.0.1~web-dev: Failed to exec web-dev script
14 verbose stack Error: ClubApp@0.0.1 web-dev: `webpack-dev-server --content-base web/public/ --config web/webpack/web.dev.config.js --port 3001 --inline --hot --colors`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid ClubApp@0.0.1
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\clark\Documents\Test\ClubApp
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "web-dev"
19 error node v6.11.0
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error ClubApp@0.0.1 web-dev: `webpack-dev-server --content-base web/public/ --config web/webpack/web.dev.config.js --port 3001 --inline --hot --colors`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ClubApp@0.0.1 web-dev script 'webpack-dev-server --content-base web/public/ --config web/webpack/web.dev.config.js --port 3001 --inline --hot --colors'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ClubApp package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     webpack-dev-server --content-base web/public/ --config web/webpack/web.dev.config.js --port 3001 --inline --hot --colors
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs ClubApp
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls ClubApp
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, did you run `npm install` before you ran `npm run web-dev`?

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough it was this as well as a few other installs. I guess, not every guide includes such simple things. It appears I was wrong, `npm` `'command'` actually adds files to the `./node_modules` folder that include everything necessary to run the project. Make your comment an answer, and enjoy the easy points!

Comment: I think people are starting to assume that everyone knows that when it isn't obvious, especially if you're new to npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run `npm install` before you try to run `npm run web-dev`